# Big Query: String to Array

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I need to convert attached image, string data type to array in Bigquery.

Any pointers?

[image: Big Query Schema]

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question preferably as editable text

Comment: Which field would you like to convert? It will also be helpful if you provide your sample and expected data.